# What is the link for Google OAuth tokens?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I try to use OAuth with google. I receive a code using a POST request to this URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
```

Then I try to get a *access token* by sending a POST request to this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

But this returns me a HTTP 404 "*Not found*" error. Is this URL wrong?

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` works for me.

Answer (score 8):

The URI that I've gotten to work for an Oauth2 token right now is

> `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`

I saw the same "*v4*" referenced in documentation, but couldn't get it to work either.

---

If you're developing your own [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) clients on the Google infrastructure, I'd recommend Google's [**OAuth 2.0 Playground**](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) which takes you through each request and response for their API's.

Comment: Presently it's v4 but I guess it changes during time

Comment: Playground link is great - found the typo in my url.

Comment: **UPDATE March 2020** After some trial and error, the following URL for getting a _refresh token_ worked for me: [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token)

Answer (score 2):

Oauth has been deprecated by Google. For OAuth 2.0, Try their [well-known OpenID Configuration link](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) which shows:

```
"authorization_endpoint": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
```

Comment: The only caveat is that it's not updated and `"token_endpoint": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"` returns Not found

Comment: returns 404 for Get method, use Post

Comment: What counts is what is at: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
This is the location that Google provide for OIDC information shows:
"authorization_endpoint": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
And as @danipenaperez  said.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=1234567891011-t28d34tfmfk5i5865hm7kij8nvl7vdax.apps.googleusercontent.com' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=KFcsEpfLjg64ta6TtQ1QibOC' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=1/gb5fEFSu_iwbvbsXZdK8ddrJjNTD1RrXbQqdsT6wuJK'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks newer and it worked when I tried.

```
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3

Comment: I'm currently following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#android) by Google and it uses `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` as well.